# What can i write so I can test drawing money from my acount

Tags: unit-testing, xunit

Im trying to write a xunit test that test the function withdraw that the functions should return true if successful and false otherwise.

I could write to unit test that just test if I input a value! How can I write so I can test that if I draw out more than Deposit so it will return false ?

```
BankAccount account = new Account();

account.Deposit(500);  // true

account.Withdraw(1000);  // false, not enough money on the account

public class BankAccount 
{

    private double balance = 0;

    public double GetBalance() { return this.balance; }  

    public bool Deposit(double amount) { return false; }  

    public bool Withdraw(double amount) { return false; }  // << test this

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, to perform this behavior, I think that your withdraw method in your class would need to change as follows:

```
public class BankAccount 
{

    ...

    public bool Withdraw(double amount) 
    { 
        if ((balance - amount) < 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        // withdraw procedure
    } 

}
```

Then the corresponding test could be as follows:

```
[Fact]
public void BankAccount_Withdraw_ShouldPreventOverdraft()
{
    var account = new BankAccount();    //Initializes balance to 0
    Assert.False(account.Withdraw(1));
}
```

And if you wish to test it with deposits.

```
[Fact]
public void BankAccount_Withdraw_ShouldPreventOverdraftAfterDeposit()
{
    var account = new BankAccount();    //Initializes balance to 0
    account.Deposit(1)
    Assert.False(account.Withdraw(2));
}
```

As a tip for testing: a general guideline is to set up the environment you desire beforehand (the state of the bank account), perform the action being tested (withdrawal greater than balance), and then assert that the system is in the correct state after the tested action (the response from `Withdraw(...)` being false).